# How to add a point-feature shapefile to map using cartopy

Tags: cartopy

I have two shapefiles. One is a point feature shapefile, named "point.shp", the other is a polygon shapefile named "polygon.shp". Both I want to add to a map using cartopy.
I managed to add the "polygon.shp", but failed with the "point.shp".

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cartopy import crs
from cartopy.io.shapereader import Reader
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature

ax = plt.axes(projection=crs.PlateCarree())

# add the polygon file, worked
ax.add_geometries(Reader("polygon.shp").geometries(), crs.PlateCarree(), facecolor='w')

# or(also worked):
ax.add_feature(ShapelyFeature(Reader("polygon.shp").geometries(), crs.PlateCarree(), facecolor='r'))

# but these two ways both failed with the "point.shp"
ax.add_geometries(Reader("point.shp").geometries(), crs.PlateCarree())

# or, this doesn't work neither:
ax.add_feature(ShapelyFeature(Reader("polygon.shp").geometries(), crs.PlateCarree(), facecolor='r'))
```

Does any one know how to do this, or why, without retrieving all the points' x, y coords and then plotting them?

And with coordinates(x, y values), `ax.plot()` works, but `ax.scatter()` fails, why?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add_geometries currently turns a geometry into a polygon and then colours it appropriately, which of course means that when you pass points the add_geometries, the polygons are not visible. Potentially cartopy could do a better job of this in the future, but in the meantime, it sounds like you just want to use something like scatter to visualize your data.

You can achieve this by getting the x and y coordinate values out of the geometry and passing these straight on to scatter with the appropriate transform:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fname = cartopy.io.shapereader.natural_earth(resolution='10m',
                                               category='cultural',
                                               name='populated_places_simple')

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())

ax.set_title('Populated places of the world.')
ax.coastlines()

points = list(cartopy.io.shapereader.Reader(fname).geometries())

ax.scatter([point.x for point in points],
           [point.y for point in points],
           transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

plt.show()
```

[image: output]

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much first. It seems from your answer, what I'm looking for is impossible, at least for now. I was just wondering if there's an easy way to just read a point-feature shp file and add it to the map like the polygon-feature shp file.

Comment: And you did answered my second question. It turns out that the `ax.scatter` seems fail due to an overlay problem, since I've added something else on the map, adding a `zorder` arg will make it work. However it is strange that even though with something else on the map, when `ax.plot` is capable to just plot a point without specfying a zorder, just changing to `ax.scatter` literally in the same line needs a `zorder` arg. I mean, by default, shouldn't point be on top of polyline which on top on polygon (point > line > polygon)?

Comment: @gepcel - the behaviour is inherited from matplotlib I believe. If you think otherwise, please feel free to open an issue on the github page and we can try to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: I just knew about cartopy very lately. Thought many things I don't understand, and most of times, `scatter` or `annotate` or ... just shows nothing, but mostly it's just my misunderstanding, not an issue. I guess I'll just keep practing. And I'll keeping asking questings, thank you for your patient.

Comment: @gepcel - The transform keyword is key. If you forget it, it assumes that the data has been specified in the coordinates of the map being produced, not lats & lons.

Comment: Bummer as this is much slower than using `add_geometries`.