# A Shapely MultiLinestring shows up as a MultiPolygon in Pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapely, cartopy

**Aim :** drawing MultiPolygon (land) and MultiLinestring (rivers) on the same pyplot Figure. Coloring the land white.

**Problem :** it seems the MultiLinestring is shown as a MultiPolygon built by closing all its Linestrings automatically to make them Polygons

**Telltale:** when coloring the MultiPolygon white, it doesn't color what seems to be Polygons made out of the Linestrings from the MultiLinestring

Here's the reproductible code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature

# creates a map
map_projection = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0.0, globe=None)
map_figure = plt.figure()
map_subplot = plt.axes(projection=map_projection)
# limits the display bounds of the map
map_subplot.set_extent((5.2, 31.4, 35, 54.3), crs=map_projection)

# adding land from a local shp (source : Natural Earth website)
# facecolor = white
landshpfilename = "Central Europe _ lands minus lakes.shp"
landshapereader = shpreader.Reader(landshpfilename)
landshape_feature = ShapelyFeature(landshapereader.geometries(), map_projection, facecolor='white',edgecolor='black')
map_subplot.add_feature(landshape_feature)

# adding large river from a local shp (source : Natural Earth website)
# edgecolor = blue
largeriversshpfilename = "Central Europe _ large rivers minus lakes.shp"
largeriversshapereader = shpreader.Reader(largeriversshpfilename)
largeriversshape_feature = ShapelyFeature(largeriversshapereader.geometries(), map_projection,edgecolor='blue')
map_subplot.add_feature(largeriversshape_feature)

# verifying the geom_type of the first objects in the shapefiles
# putting it as a title
land_geom_type_text = ' '.join(['lands geom_type :',next(landshape_feature.geometries()).geom_type])
river_geom_type_text = ' '.join(['rivers geom_type :',next(largeriversshape_feature.geometries()).geom_type])
map_figure.suptitle('\n'.join([land_geom_type_text,river_geom_type_text]))

plt.show()
```

Here's the result :
[rendered map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yjRW.png)

**Question :** How to fix it ?

Comment: We don't have access to the .shp files you're referencing in your code. Can you change them to a simple geojson reference? You can read shapefiles (and convert them to a json format) with [fiona](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona)

Comment: The answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340427/how-to-add-a-point-feature-shapefile-to-map-using-cartopy) shows that cartopy may somehow turns a geometry into a polygon and then colours it appropriately.

Comment: @Micks Ketches I don't think the shapefiles are relevant here, but for the record, they're clips of "Land" and "Rivers + lake centerlines" at http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/.
Also, seeing gepcel's answer, I guess I'll have to find another way of plotting them, from geojson or wkt for example.

Comment: @gepcel Thanks for the answer. I understand from pelson's answer that my problem is unsolvable for the time being.
Your question and its answer date back from 2014. Have you filed an issue ticket to the Cartopy project team since ?

Comment: @Tehem No, I haven't filed any issues. Back then, I was looking for a way to plot points, and I ended up using `plt.scatter`.

Comment: Quick solution: set ``facecolor='none'`` (notice that is the string "none", not the None object - this is a matplotlib-ism...)

Answer (score 2):

Setting `facecolor='none'` will prevent matplotlib from filling in the underlying path that is produced. A quick reproducible case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature


ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# Create a feature for States/Admin 1 regions at 1:50m from Natural Earth
states_provinces = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature(
    category='physical',
    name='rivers_lake_centerlines',
    scale='110m',
    )

ax.add_feature(states_provinces, edgecolor='gray', linewidth=5)
ax.coastlines()
```

[image: Filled rivers, booo!]

Keeping everything else the same, but changing the feature construction to set no facecolor yields the desired result:

```
states_provinces = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature(
    category='physical',
    name='rivers_lake_centerlines',
    scale='110m',
    facecolor='none'
    )
```

[image: Rivers, yay!]

Comment: I had managed to get the right look by giving the river polygons the _same_ facecolor as the land. In my case, I turned both `'white'` and the river polygons don't show. Your solution, `'none'` (and not `None` as I had tried earlier), works better I think because it's adaptive. However, I'm afraid I'll run into some trouble when checking if Points are over river Linestrings, or inside land polygons, since the rivers still have their own polygons on top. I'll get to this later.